# Use a class type as field in Chapel

Tags: chapel

I have the following Chapel code, but it seems inefficient.

```
class Student {
    var name: string;
    proc init(name:string) {this.name = name;}
}

class GoodStudent : Student {
    var likesToDate: BadStudent; 
    proc init(name:string) {super.init(name=name);}
}

class BadStudent : Student {
    proc init(name:string) {super.init(name=name);}
}

var students: [1..0] Student;

students.push_back(new GoodStudent("baby"));
students.push_back(new GoodStudent("some other girl"));
students.push_back(new BadStudent("patrick swayze"));

for s in students {
    for t in students {
        if t:GoodStudent != nil {
            var tt = t:GoodStudent; 
            writeln(tt.name, " :will date?: ", s.name);
            if s:tt.likesToDate.type  != nil {
                writeln(" ... YES!");
            } else {
                writeln(" ... NO!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using an empty `GoodStudent` to compare types for potential dates.  I would rather keep the `GoodStudent` type as a field variable.  What is the correct syntax so that Baby can get her date and stay out of the corner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like any other variables, class fields can be declared using the `type` keyword in place of `var` to specify that they represent a type instead of a value.  Classes with a `type` field are generic - the class initializer can set the field to any type when the class is instantiated.  This [primer example](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/latest/primers/genericClasses.html) demonstrates using a type field in a generic class.

Since the `GoodStudent` is only interested in the type of students she `likesToDate`, and not any particular instances, that field can be replaced with a type field.  The type field does not take up any memory during program execution like the version declared with `var` does.

```
class GoodStudent : Student {
  type likesToDate = BadStudent; 
  proc init(name:string) {super.init(name=name);}
}
```

Then, your main loops can be slightly modified to access the type field instead of going through the field's `.type`.

```
for s in students {
  for t in students {
    var tt = t:GoodStudent; 
    if tt != nil {
      writeln(tt.name, " :will date?: ", s.name);
      if s:tt.likesToDate  != nil {
        writeln(" ... YES!");
      } else {
        writeln(" ... NO!");
      }
    }
  }
}
```